# Strange Issue With Bootstrap Timepicker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, timepicker

I have a form with a bootstrap timepicker, the form is meant for editing purposes meaning on page load data is loaded from the database to it's respective fields in the form. However this works well for all other fields but datepicker and time picker.  The value itself changes when you look at the page source, but the value in the page source is different than what is actually showing on the page:

**Inspect Element:**
[image]

**Form Display:**
[image]

What i noticed is that the actual value form the database is displayed on page load but then it changes by itself as soon as the page  is done loading which is making me believe there is some javascript that is responsible for this bad behaviour.

Comment: can you show us how you're populating the HTML ?

Comment: via PHP as in --> value="<?php echo $start_time; ?>"

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the time in another format.

If it is this component: http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/, you must set it like this: `02:00 PM`